# How to determine if a type is in the inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance

I need to determine if an object has a specific type in it's inheritance hierarchy, however I can't find a good way of doing it.

An very basic example version of my classes are:

```
Public Class Domain

End Class

Public Class DerivedOne
    Inherits Domain

End Class

Public Class DerivedTwo
    Inherits DerivedOne

End Class

Public Class DerivedThree
    Inherits Domain

End Class
```

The following does work, however it isn't very elegant in my opinion. Also the more levels of inheritance that get created, the more checks need to be done and it would be easy to forget this piece of code needs to be updated.

```
If GetType(T) Is GetType(Domain) OrElse _
    GetType(T).BaseType Is GetType(Domain) OrElse _
    GetType(T).BaseType.BaseType Is GetType(Domain) Then

End If
```

Is there a way of getting 'Is type of Domain anywhere in T's inheritance hierarchy'?

(Answers welcome in C# or VB.NET)

---

**UPDATE**

One bit of vital information I missed out due to my own idiocy!

**T is a Type object (from the class' generic type)**

Comment: Are you working with a non-null instance or are you working with a `Type` metadata object? (The result of `GetType(T)` [ `typeof(T)` in C#])

Comment: It is a `Type` object.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method.

In VB:

```
If GetType(Domain).IsAssignableFrom(GetType(DerivedThree)) Then
```

In C#:

```
if (typeof(Domain).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DerivedThree)))
```

Comment: Not sure why downvotes, I was just about to post this. (I think maybe you've got your types the wrong way around though.)

Comment: @Rawling - you're right, thanks.  Will fix!  And yes, I wish downvoters explained themselves too.

Comment: @DanPuzey I just tried this and noticed the same issue, I will give it a through test with my actual code.

Comment: I note that this method is correctly named. The original poster asked for a method that determines if one type is *in the inheritance hierarchy* of another; this method does not answer that question. This method answers the question "can an instance of one type be assigned to a variable of the other type?" which is a different question. A `List<Giraffe>` may be assigned to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Animal>` but `IEnumerable<Animal>` does not appear in the inheritance hierarchy of `List<Giraffe>`.

Comment: Oooh, damn you Eric Lippert :P  That's only an issue since co-/contra-variance has been around, right?  Or has the CLR supported such things much longer?

Comment: @DanPuzey The CLR has supported co- and contravariance since .Net 2.0. It's just that the support was added to C# only in version 4.0 and BCL interfaces and delegates were marked as co-/contravariant at that time too.

Answer (score 6):

Why is nobody mentioning `Type.IsSubclassOf(Type)` ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=netframework-4.7.2

Careful, it returns false if called for two equal types `;)`

Answer (score -3):

How about [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

```
if(obj is Domain)
{
    // 
}
```

Comment: Nop, doesn't work, i'm here looking for a way to do it and I thoug the is operator was the answer. or at leat on .net 3.5 doesn't work like that, hadn't tried it 4.0 or 4.5